# Pyspark Job with Dataproc on GCP

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to running a `pyspark` job, but I keep getting job failure for this reason:

*Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found at: `https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/f8f8e95794e0457d80ea1b0c4df8d815?project=long-state-352923&region=us-central1 gcloud dataproc jobs wait 'f8f8e95794e0457d80ea1b0c4df8d815' --region 'us-central1' --project 'long-state-352923' **...***`

here is also my code in running the job:

```
`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('spark_hdfs_to_hdfs') \
.getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

MASTER_NODE_INSTANCE_NAME="cluster-d687-m"
log_files_rdd = sc.textFile('hdfs://{}/data/logs_example/*'.format(MASTER_NODE_INSTANCE_NAME))

splitted_rdd = log_files_rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(" "))
selected_col_rdd = splitted_rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[3], x[5], x[6]))

columns = ["ip","date","method","url"]
logs_df = selected_col_rdd.toDF(columns)
logs_df.createOrReplaceTempView('logs_df')

sql = """
  SELECT
  url,
  count(*) as count
  FROM logs_df
  WHERE url LIKE '%/article%'
  GROUP BY url
  """
article_count_df = spark.sql(sql)
print(" ### Get only articles and blogs records ### ")
article_count_df.show(5)`
```

i don't seem to understand the reasoning why its failing.

Is there a problem with code?

Comment: Could you add the command used to submit the job? You can check driver, executor logs and Spark UI. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output

Comment: what is the content of the logs?

Comment: @Dagang what's a good way to go about this, when the cluster is "ephemeral"? We're facing this issue often and I suspect the error is logged *somewhere*, but not sure where.

Comment: You can still find logs in Cloud Logging for ephemeral clusters.